# Можно ли указать только 1 параметр по умполчанию в методе класса( а так же в функции))

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class fraction
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
public:
    fraction(){}
    void getfraction(int x, char f = '/', int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = f;
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << a << '/' << b << std::endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    fraction fr1;

    return 0;
}
```

среда ругаетс на отсутствие последнего указания параметра по умолчанию, можно ли указать только 1 из параметров метода по умолчанию(кроме последнего)?

Comment: Нет, значение по-умолчанию можно указывать только начиная с последнего параметра. Это кстати и к параметрам шаблонов относится. Однако можно сделать перегруженную функцию с двумя параметрами, которая будет вызывать эту функцию подставляя значение по-умолчанию для недостающего параметра.

Comment: Это из-за того что компилятор читает справа-налево?

Comment: Нет, это из-за того, что при вызове функции параметры указываются слева направо.

Comment: а если у нас 5 параметров, 1 параметр по умолчанию указан, достаточно последний тоже указать по умолчанию, или тогда все остальные параметры тоже должны быть указаны по умолчанию?

Comment: Если для какого-то параметра указано значение по-умолчанию, то занчание по-умолчанию должно быть указано и *для всех последующих* параметров.

Comment: Спасибо большое.